# How to declare in scope?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, scope

I'm trying to read in how many numbers are in a text file since the total was not defined. 
What I'm trying to do, is write a while loop that reads the file until there are no more elements to read. And inside the while loop, cin will read in the elements and will be pushed back into the vector data. But "i" is not define in scope. How do i declare it in the scope, or is there a better approach for this?

```
void read_vector(vector<int> &data) {

    cout << "Using read function!" << endl;
    //int i = data.size();
    while (data.size() != 0){
        cin >> data[i];
        data.push_back(data[i]);
    }

} // read_function()
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. I would *guess* that both attempts at answers so far are correct. But the presented code makes so little sense that it could be anything, really.

Comment: If reading from a file, why `cin`?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how many numbers are there in the input you can use `while(cin>>temp)` to read all the number there is until you reach EOF or an invalid token (not an integer).
So you don't need the variable `i`. Just create a temporary `int` read the input and `push_back` it into the `vector`.

```
int temp;
while (cin>>temp){
    data.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: This is guesswork and should be a comment.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: No, comments are *not* for guesses, except guesses that can yield more information for a later answer (and are not enough to solve the problem on their own). Attempted answers, guesswork or otherwise, are only for answers, where they can be downvoted if wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare and initialize a variable named `i`, then you do

```
int i = 0;
```

However, `data[i]` won't work because there are no elements in the vector yet. You need to use `data.push_back()` in order to add the elements. Since you `push_back()` adds elements to the end of the list, you don't need the index variable at all. So the declaration is unnecessary anyway.

Comment: "there are no elements in the vector yet" is pure guesswork. Your telepathy circuit may of course be better than mine, which unfortunately is non-functional. But I doubt it, since it's the same manufacturer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This seems very likely to me since the OP is writing a function to read data into the vector.